# How to run executable with Python code inside

Tags: python, bash, sh

I have the following file:

```
$ cat my_exec.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env python

print(10)
```

It should just print `10`. However, I can't get it to do so:

```
$ sudo ./my_exec.sh

sudo: ./my_exec.sh: command not found

$ sh my_exec.sh 

my_exec.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `10'
my_exec.sh: line 3: `print(10)'
```

How do I run my file?

Comment: Rename your script to `my_exec.py` and update the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: `sudo` means "super user do". Do you need your script to be executed with elevated/different permissions? If not, don't use `sudo`. `sh` executes a shell script in POSIX-compliance mode, so you don't want that either. Have you tried `./my_exec.sh` ?

Comment: I did `sudo` because simply doing `./my_exec.sh` resulted in permission denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it via the python command:

```
$ python my_exec.sh
```

To run it as simply ./my_exec.sh, you need to make the file executable first:

```
$ chmod 755 my_exec.sh
```

Also note that by convention python files end in .py .

Answer (score 2):

- Change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python`
- Change the filename to my_exec.py, as is convention for python files
- You can run with `python my_exec.py`
- You can `chmod +x my_exec.py` and then `./my_exec.py`

Answer (score 0):

You must enter the directory that you have saved you file through the cmd with cd command. After that you just execute the file with : python name_of_the_file.py . But first you must make it executable with chmod command

For example if you have saved your file at Desktop with the name mycode.py :

```
cd Desktop
chmod +x mycode.py
python mycode.py
```